# Does the JavaScript interpreter interprets code twice or once?

Tags: javascript

It doesn't really say anywhere and I'd really love to know.

Does JavaScript firstly reads a file, assigns memory to the variables, moves their declarations to the top of the stack and then runs the second time with executing, or does it read it all in one go somehow?

Sorry if repeating, but i havent found this specific question or a specific answer to this question either.

Comment: I'd say it depends on which interpreter you're using, but from my education on the standard protocol for translation, the interpreter converts the program into a giant parse tree consisting of every token in the program, which is then cherry-picked and converted token-by-token bottom-up into machine code, and since JS is interpreted this is immediately executed. So in this case the code itself is read once and then the parse tree is dealt with to run the code, but technically the logic of the code is read twice (once as source code, once as a parse tree).

Comment: my guess would be it parses once, interprets once?

Comment: I guess this question needs an edit, since i really want to get to the bottom of this, but still can\t find the info on how to hoisting actually happens behind the sceenes.